# Failed creation of IAM Autoscale role when adding autoscale to a ECS task

Tags: autoscaling, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am adding some auto scaling setting to a ECS task

[image]

The idea is I will spawn new service when the length of the  message  queue increase, otherwise decrease

After I put in the definition as defined above, I got the following error message:

[image]

**Failed creation of IAM Autoscale role**

> IAM Autoscale role could not create ecsAutoscaleRole: User:
>   arn:aws:iam::796668560264:user/play-admin is not authorized to
>   perform: iam:CreateRole on resource:
>   arn:aws:iam::796668560264:role/ecsAutoscaleRole (Service:
>   AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
>   Request ID: 44ca4263-4aa3-11e7-b3ad-23809db2c1f6)

I have already followed the instruction here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/autoscale_IAM_role.html to create the role **ecsAutoscaleRole**, so what is missing?

[image]

Question: How can I fix this? I do not want to grant my current IAM user any right to create new IAM users.

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing to create a new role during service/autoscale configuration.

Simply select existing role that you already created in IAM and it wont attempt to use your user's credentials to create a new role.